# Using definition to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2n^2+5n}{n^2+2}=2$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

I want to know if this is correct: I have to use the definition to show

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2n^2+5n}{n^2+2}=2$$

what I did was: let $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$\left|\frac{2n^2+5n}{n^2+2}-2\right|<\varepsilon$$

So,
$$\left|\frac{2n^2+5n}{n^2+2}-2\right|=\left|\frac{5n-4}{n^2+2}\right|\leq\frac{5n}{n^2+2}+\frac{4}{n^{2}+2}$$
and, since
$$\frac{5n}{n^2+2}+\frac{4}{n^{2}+2}\leq\frac{9n}{n^2+2}\leq\frac{9n}{n^2}=\frac{9}{n}$$
then for $n>n_{0}$ with
$$n_{0}=\frac{9}{\varepsilon}$$
the limit is proved.

Is it correct?

Comment: As an alternative we have $$\dfrac{2n^2+5n}{n^2+2}=\dfrac{2n^2+4+5n-4}{n^2+2}=\dfrac{2(n^2+2)}{n^2+2}+\dfrac{5n-4}{n^2+2}=2+\dfrac{5n-4}{n^2+2}$$

and we reduces to prove that $\dfrac{5n-4}{n^2+2} \to 0$ and since

$$0\le \dfrac{5n-4}{n^2+2} \le \dfrac{5n}{n^2}=\frac5{n}$$

we reduces to prove that $\frac1{n}\to 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally this is good, but there are some things I would change.

When you start, you want to consider an arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$ and then find an $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that your second displayed formula is true for all $n>n_0$.

The following calculations are perfectly fine, but in the end you need to be slightly more careful as $\frac{9}{\varepsilon}$ does not need to be a natural number. So, instead choosing $n_0>\frac{9}{\varepsilon}$ (which is possible by the Archimedean property of the natural numbers) is a better idea.

Comment: Yes, I know. but I wrote it in a better way here at home.

Comment: I think you mean the Archimedean property of the reals?

Comment: @bananamilk no, I think I want the one of the natural numbers, because $n_0$ should be a natural number?! But maybe I am mixing up names.

Comment: I think we are referring to the same thing: Informally, the Archimedean property of the reals states that for any real number $r$, there exists a natural number greater than $r$.

Comment: Then, we're definitely talking about the same thing.

Comment: @JonasLenz :  It's the archimedean property of the reals, because $ 9 / \epsilon $ is a real.  (If $ \epsilon $ were an infinitesimal hyperreal, then you couldn't do this, because the hyperreals don't satisfy the archimedean property.)

Answer (score 4):

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N> \frac{5}{\epsilon} : \forall n > N$ it is verify: $|\frac{2n^2+5n}{n^2+2}|=|\frac{5n-4}{n^2+2}|<|\frac{5n}{n^2+2}|<|\frac{5n}{n^2}|=|\frac{5}{n}|<|\frac{5}{N}| < |\frac{5}{5/ \epsilon}|=\epsilon$
When we used the following inequalities.
-$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|5n-4|<|5n|$
-$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n^2+2 > n^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n^2+2} <\frac{1}{n^2}$
-$\forall n > N \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N}$

As I am just a student I hope that this is correct and that this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

There are technical details that are incorrect, even though the general idea that you have works.

Firstly, you can't start with: "let $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$". Definition of limit says $$(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists n_0\in\mathbb N)\ n\geq n_0 \implies |a_n-L|<\varepsilon$$
which means that $|a_n-L|<\varepsilon$ should be a consequence, not assumption.
To correct this you write down some equivalences, from your work we could write
$$\left|\frac{2n^2+5n}{n^2+2}-2\right|<\varepsilon \iff \left|\frac{5n-4}{n^2+2}\right| < \varepsilon$$
Further, you correctly conclude that $$\left|\frac{5n-4}{n^2+2}\right|\leq \frac 9 n$$ (even though you have equality at one place which should be inequality, but I'll assume it's a typo).

A correct way to continue is something like this: if $n\in\mathbb N$ is such that $\frac 9 n < \varepsilon$, then we have $$\left|\frac{2n^2+5n}{n^2+2}-2\right| = \left|\frac{5n-4}{n^2+2}\right| \leq \frac 9 n < \varepsilon.\tag{1}$$

Finally, you define $n_0 = \frac 9\varepsilon$, but this is not ok, because $\frac 9\varepsilon$ won't be integer in general. The cleanest way to do this is to appeal to Archimedean axiom which in this case states that there exists $n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac 9{n_0} < \varepsilon$. Now,
$$n\geq n_0 \implies \frac 9n\leq \frac 9{n_0} < \varepsilon$$ which together with $(1)$ implies $$\left|\frac{2n^2+5n}{n^2+2}-2\right|<\varepsilon$$ which we wanted to prove.